# HTML Failed parsing 'srcset' attribute value since it has an unknown descriptor on images - React - Webpack

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack

Might be worth mentioning that I am using React and Webpack.

Example of this:

`<img src="https://increasify.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/default-image.png" srcset="http://www.rangerwoodperiyar.com/images/joomlart/demo/default.jpg x2"`

My goal is to take advantage of the `srcset` attribute to detect if the screen density is x2 to let the browser determine the use of the larger image.

Image shows fine, but it's not using the larger image described in the `srcset` attribute for retina or higher density screens.

It is also showing the following Errors in the console:

- `Failed parsing 'srcset' attribute value since it has an unknown descriptor.` coming from `vendor.bundle.js`
- `Dropped srcset candidate "<URL>"`
- `Dropped srcset candidate "http://www.rangerwoodperiyar.com/images/joomlart/demo/default.jpg"`

I'm using the latest version of Chrome currently `Version 70.0.3538.110`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the issue, I had put `x2` when it should be `2x` silly mistake.

Answer (score 2):

A whitespace in the name of the image will also trigger this error:

`assets/logo/logo 2x.png 2x,`

must be changed to

`assets/logo/logo2x.png 2x,`

Comment: You can also replace the spaces with `%20` (encodeURI)  and that'll work